# Зависает Ubuntu с VLC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc

помогите разобраться в проблеме.
Данные Ubuntu 20,04 и VLC
И так ситуация такая - при просмотре некоторых файлов плеер зависает, и сразу после этого полностью зависает графический интерфейс. Все что получается это выйти, и там перезагрузить.
То есть я нажимаю ctrl+alt+f1 попадаю на экран входа, и там нажимаю перезагрузить.
Вызвать консоль не могу, процесс так же убить не могу.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?
И как нужно поступить? Как выяснить в чем проблема?
В журналах смотрел по метке vlc там вроде пусто. Спасибо

Comment: так ничего в голову не приходит, но перезагрузка уж как то очень сурово. У меня такое было с mpv, плюнул не разобравшись. Но если нажать ctrl+alt+f2 попадаете в консоль, где логинетесь и убиваете процесс. Что то вроде killall -9 vlc

Comment: @maint Большое спасибо, к сожалению эта комбинация клавиш  у меня не работает вообще. Что сделать что бы заработала? Да, согласен что это сурово...

Comment: сейчас только отправил, правда в виртуалке ctrl+alt+f[2-4] и вышел на консоль. Не очень понятно почему вы не вышли. Ну это ладно. У вас стандартная ubuntu? Правда с mate в качестве DE у меня

Comment: Я канешно ответ вам не дам, у меня была похожая ситуация тольоко на `Kubuntu` и система полностью зависала, никакие комбинации клавиш не работали. Но, я включил `ssh` демон и мог во время такого зависания подключится по `ssh` и смотреть логи системы. Правда и это мне не помогло, меня спасло замена видеокарты)) а в винде проблем небыло

Comment: @Максим Большое спасибо, проблема решилась. Видимо система таки не совсем совместима с видеокартой. Пришлось перейти обратно на окна, хотя не сильно горел желанием.

Comment: @maint Да, у меня обычная версия. Которая к сожалению не совсем совместима с встроенным видео. Решение так и не нашлось в течении 2х дней, пришлось вернуться обратно на  win10. Большое спасибо